# Create 1 text file per every 100 Rows Of Data

Tags: vba, excel, spread

Let's say:

1. I have 1,000 Rows of separate information in an Excel spreadsheet. (1 Column, 1,000 Rows)
2. I want to save each 100 rows as its own file name. (`workbook1.txt`, `workbook2.txt`, `workbook3.txt`, etc.)

Currently, I do this manually:

- I will highlight 100 Rows.
- I use the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy)
  then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (New) to create a new file, then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste) then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> To Save the File,
  naming the file with the default name assigned when using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, So it would be saved as `workbook1`, `workbook2`, `workbook3`...

I am saving them as text files (.txt).

Is is possible to automate this process, maybe a bat file or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple VBA script like:

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
Do While counter < 10
Range("A1:A100").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\test" & CStr(counter) & ".txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A101:A1000").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

Saving as xlTextMSDOS saves only active sheet so You do not have to create new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux system, there is a command line utility called "split" that does exactly this:
split a text file in N file of N (lines, bytes, words).

cat original_file.csv | split -l 1000

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is simply easier to copy everything into a new worksheet and remove what you do not wish to retain. A [Worksheet.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx)  to no location will open a new, blank workbook with a single worksheet; that being a copy of the original.

```
Sub split_100()
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, fn As String

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = false 'uncomment when it works right for you

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lr Step 100
            .Copy
            With ActiveWorkbook
                With .Worksheets(1)
                    If i > 1 Then _
                        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(i - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    .Cells(101, 1).Resize(lr, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
                fn = Environ("TMP") & "\Workbook" & Format(Int(i / 100) + 1, "00") 'no extension; leave that for xlTextWindows
                'Application.DisplayAlerts = False  'uncomment to avoid overwrite warnings
                .SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After removing what is not wanted, a [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) brings the cycle to a [Workbook.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx). There are a number of TXT formats to choose from, the above uses the [xlTextWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) xlFileFormat.